# xsl for each node create collapse/expand panel

Tags: html, css, xml, xslt

I am creating an accordion panel for each event(node) I have. I was able to create the accordion panels, but I can only collapse/expand the first panel. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm using some bootstrap and some of my own ugly css. I believe some of the bootstrap style sheets are preventing me to create my own css style sheets so that is why I am currently adding css to individual tags (temporary).

xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="FavoriteEvents.xsl"?>
<all>
  <Spark_Dev_Apps_>
    <Date>11/21/2018</Date>
    <Description>descriptions</Description>
    <Document>spark.txt</Document>
    <Image>sparkdev.png</Image>
    <Location>PG6116</Location>
    <RSVP_link>sparkdev.com</RSVP_link>
    <Sponsor>Spark Dev</Sponsor>
    <Time>8pm</Time>
    <Type>Mobile App</Type>
  </Spark_Dev_Apps_>
  <CTF>
    <Date>11/23/2018</Date>
    <Description>description</Description>
    <Document>ctf.txt</Document>
    <Image>ctf.png</Image>
    <Location>PG5</Location>
    <RSVP_link>fiu.com/hacks</RSVP_link>
    <Sponsor>Moreno Hacks</Sponsor>
    <Time>8pm</Time>
    <Type>Cyber Security</Type>
  </CTF>
  <Unity_for_Advanced>
    <Date>11/23/2018</Date>
    <Description>Description text</Description>
    <Document>unityDoc.txt</Document>
    <Image>unity.png</Image>
    <Location>PG6 105</Location>
    <Sponsor>Unity</Sponsor>
    <Time>3pm</Time>
    <Type>Game Dev</Type>
    <Website>www.unity.com</Website>
  </Unity_for_Advanced>
  <Big_O_for_Beginners>
    <Date>11/24/2018</Date>
    <Description>Description text</Description>
    <Document>BigODoc.txt</Document>
    <Image>BigO.png</Image>
    <Location>PG6 105</Location>
    <Sponsor>Facebook</Sponsor>
    <Time>5pm</Time>
    <Type>Database</Type>
    <Website>www.facebook.com</Website>
  </Big_O_for_Beginners>
  <Smash_Bros_Tournament>
    <Date>11/25/2018</Date>
    <Description>Fun stuffffff</Description>
    <Document>upe.txt</Document>
    <Image>upe.png</Image>
    <Location>PG6 116</Location>
    <RSVP_link>Upe.com</RSVP_link>
    <Sponsor>UPE</Sponsor>
    <Time>7pm</Time>
    <Type>Game Dev</Type>
  </Smash_Bros_Tournament>
  <JR_Code_Academy>
    <Date>11/27/2018</Date>
    <Description>Description text</Description>
    <Document>UPEDoc.txt</Document>
    <Image>upetutors.png</Image>
    <Location>Braddock SR High School</Location>
    <Sponsor>UPE</Sponsor>
    <Time>12pm</Time>
    <Type>Teach Code</Type>
    <Website>www.UPE.com</Website>
  </JR_Code_Academy>
  <Advanced_SQL>
    <Date>11/29/2018</Date>
    <Description>Description text</Description>
    <Document>BigODoc.txt</Document>
    <Image>BigO.png</Image>
    <Location>PG6 105</Location>
    <Sponsor>UPE</Sponsor>
    <Time>5pm</Time>
    <Type>Database</Type>
    <Website>www.facebook.com</Website>
  </Advanced_SQL>
  <Robot_Wars>
    <Date>12/03/2018</Date>
    <Description>Description text</Description>
    <Document>RobotDoc.txt</Document>
    <Image>robots.png</Image>
    <Location>PG6 106</Location>
    <Sponsor>UPE</Sponsor>
    <Time>2pm</Time>
    <Type>Robotics</Type>
    <Website>www.robotwars.com</Website>
  </Robot_Wars>
  <Wireshark_for_Beginners>
    <Date>12/05/2018</Date>
    <Description>Description text</Description>
    <Document>wiresharkDoc.txt</Document>
    <Image>wireshark.png</Image>
    <Location>ECS 243</Location>
    <Sponsor>Wireshark</Sponsor>
    <Time>2pm</Time>
    <Type>Networking</Type>
    <Website>www.Wireshark.com</Website>
  </Wireshark_for_Beginners>
  <VR_Hacks>
    <Date>12/05/2018</Date>
    <Description>Description text</Description>
    <Document>oculusriftDoc.txt</Document>
    <Image>oculusrift.png</Image>
    <Location>PG6 106</Location>
    <Sponsor>Oculus Rift</Sponsor>
    <Time>1pm</Time>
    <Type>Alt Reality</Type>
    <Website>www.oculusrift.com</Website>
  </VR_Hacks>
  <HTML_5_Tips___Tricks>
    <Date>12/12/2018</Date>
    <Description>Description text</Description>
    <Document>web.txt</Document>
    <Image>web.png</Image>
    <Location>ECS 237</Location>
    <Sponsor>FIU/</Sponsor>
    <Time>4pm</Time>
    <Type>Web Dev</Type>
    <Website>www.fiu.com/web</Website>
  </HTML_5_Tips___Tricks>
  <Big_Network_Management_Easy>
    <Date>12/12/2018</Date>
    <Description>Description text</Description>
    <Document>network.txt</Document>
    <Image>networking.png</Image>
    <Location>ECS 237</Location>
    <Sponsor>FIU/Johnson</Sponsor>
    <Time>4pm</Time>
    <Type>Networking</Type>
    <Website>www.fiu.com/networking</Website>
  </Big_Network_Management_Easy>
  <Code_for_Kids>
    <Date>12/15/2018</Date>
    <Description>Description text</Description>
    <Document>UPEDoc.txt</Document>
    <Image>upetutors.png</Image>
    <Location>Jack Gordon Elementary</Location>
    <Sponsor>UPE</Sponsor>
    <Time>12pm</Time>
    <Type>Teach Code</Type>
    <Website>www.UPE.com</Website>
  </Code_for_Kids>
  <Android_App_Dev>
    <Date>12/17/2018</Date>
    <Description>Description text</Description>
    <Document>androidDoc.txt</Document>
    <Image>androidapp.png</Image>
    <Location>PG6 105</Location>
    <Sponsor>Android</Sponsor>
    <Time>2pm</Time>
    <Type>Mobile App</Type>
    <Website>www.android.com/students</Website>
  </Android_App_Dev>
  <iOS_App_Dev>
    <Date>12/28/2018</Date>
    <Description>Description text</Description>
    <Document>appleDoc.txt</Document>
    <Image>iOSapp.png</Image>
    <Location>PG6 106</Location>
    <Sponsor>Apple</Sponsor>
    <Time>5pm</Time>
    <Type>Mobile App</Type>
    <Website>www.apple.com/students</Website>
  </iOS_App_Dev>
</all>
```

xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="html" version="5.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Impulse</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poiret+One" type="text/css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>


    <body style="font-family: 'Poiret One', cursive; background-image: url(png/BG01dark.jpg);
        background-size: cover; background-position: center; background-repeat: none; background-attachment: fixed;">
        <div class="container">
            <center><font style="color: white; font-size: 50px; text-shadow: 2px 2px 3px #000000;">
                Impulse</font></center>
            <center><p><font style="color: white; font-size: 20px; text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000000;">
                Your friendly computer science event organizer</font></p></center>

            <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
            <xsl:for-each select="all/*">
            <div class="panel panel-default" style="background: rgba(255,255,255.75);" >
              <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                  <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapse2">
                      <xsl:if test="Type = 'Careers'">
                          <img style="background: rgba(255,255,255.75); width:45px; height:45px;
                          border: 3px solid green; border-radius: 10px; padding: 7px;"
                                  src="png/career.png" alt="Careers">Careers</img>
                      </xsl:if>
                      <xsl:if test="Type = 'Database'">
                          <img style="background: rgba(255,255,255.75); width:45px; height:45px;
                          border: 3px solid blue; border-radius: 10px; padding: 7px;"
                               src="png/database.png" alt="Database">Database</img>
                      </xsl:if>
                      <xsl:if test="Type = 'Game Dev'">
                          <img style="background: rgba(255,255,255.75); width:45px; height:45px;
                          border: 3px solid red; border-radius: 10px; padding: 7px;"
                               src="png/gamepad.png" alt="Game Development">Game Dev</img>
                      </xsl:if>
                      <xsl:if test="Type = 'Mobile App'">
                          <img style="background: rgba(255,255,255.75); width:45px; height:45px;
                          border: 3px solid purple; border-radius: 10px; padding: 5px;"
                               src="png/mobile.png" alt="Mobile Development">Mobile Dev</img>
                      </xsl:if>
                      <xsl:if test="Type = 'Networking'">
                          <img style="background: rgba(255,255,255.75); width:45px; height:45px;
                          border: 3px solid yellow; border-radius: 10px; padding: 7px;"
                               src="png/networking.png" alt="Networking">Networking</img>
                      </xsl:if>
                      <xsl:if test="Type = 'Robotics'">
                          <img style="background: rgba(255,255,255.75); width:45px; height:45px;
                          border: 3px solid #FF6D14; border-radius: 10px; padding: 7px;"
                               src="png/robot.png" alt="Robotics">Robotics</img>
                      </xsl:if>
                      <xsl:if test="Type = 'Cyber Security'">
                          <img style="background: rgba(255,255,255.75); width:45px; height:45px;
                          border: 3px solid aqua; border-radius: 10px; padding: 7px;"
                               src="png/security.png" alt="Cyber Security">Cyber Security</img>
                      </xsl:if>
                      <xsl:if test="Type = 'Teach Code'">
                          <img style="background: rgba(255,255,255.75); width:45px; height:45px;
                          border: 3px solid #FFB34C; border-radius: 10px; padding: 7px;"
                               src="png/teach.png" alt="Teach Code">Teach Code</img>
                      </xsl:if>
                      <xsl:if test="Type = 'Alt Reality'">
                          <img style="background: rgba(255,255,255.75); width:45px; height:45px;
                          border: 3px solid #8D301D; border-radius: 10px; padding: 7px;"
                               src="png/vr.png" alt="Alternate Reality">Alt Reality</img>
                      </xsl:if>
                      <xsl:if test="Type = 'Web Dev'">
                          <img style="background: rgba(255,255,255.75); width:45px; height:45px;
                          border: 3px solid #35405A; border-radius: 10px; padding: 7px;"
                                  src="png/webdev.png" alt="Website Development">Web Dev</img>
                      </xsl:if >
                      <object hspace="20"><xsl:value-of select="name()"/></object>
                      <object align="right"><xsl:value-of select="Date"/></object>
                  </a>
                </h4>
              </div>
              <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">Event details go here
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </div>

        </div>

    </body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the conventional model for using XSLT in the browser, you use XSLT to generate an HTML/Javascript/CSS page, and then all the interaction is handled using the HTML/Javascript/CSS. Your problem therefore is to work out what HTML/Javascript/CSS you want to generate, and once you know that, writing the XSLT code to generate it should be trivial. I think the main problem with the HTML you are generating is that you are reusing the same ID values (like "collapse2") for many different elements.

You might like to consider an alternative approach: Saxon-JS allows you to do all the user-event handling within the XSLT code itself, so whenever a user event occurs (like clicking on something), the XSLT springs into life to regenerate part of the HTML page.

Comment: So there is no way I can create a variable of ID and have that increment with each event so that the appropriate panel is expanded/collapsed?

Comment: You can certainly create distinct IDs for the various elements at the time you generate them, but if you want to modify the content in response to user input events, then that's a job for Javascript, not for XSLT -- unless you decide to go down the Saxon-JS route.

Comment: Thank you, i'll look up creating distinct id's. At the moment I am not modifying any content. I have a python file that creates events and sends that to xml. So no interaction will happen on the Site, read-only basically.